# Is it possible to keep 2 users logged with Firebase Auth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building an application where users can log in with email and password. I would like to know if it is possible to log in 2 two different accounts and then be possible to switch accounts without having to enter the password again (as in instagram or gmail for example). Is there any limitation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single instance of the `FirebaseAuth` object can only have a single signed in user.

What you *can* do is create two `FirebaseApp` instances, then create a separate `FirebaseAuth` object from each of those, and have a separate user signed into each of the `FirebaseAuth` objects.

For more information, and examples of how to do this, see the Firebase documentation on [setting up multiple projects in your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application). In your case, you will be accessing a single project, but the approach will be the same.